# Display div side by side float left is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to display div side by side. The inner div is dynamic means I am using knockout binding . so the number of inner div is unknown. I want as the number of div increases a horizontal scroll bar comes. I am using float left property. But instead it display vertically as soon as i give width to the middle div it works but the problem is i dont know the width beforehand

```
<div style="width:400px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;">
    <div data-bind="foreach:Members">
        <div style="width:100px;float:left;">test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style="width:400px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;">
  <div data-bind="foreach:Members" style="white-space:nowrap; overflow:auto">
    <div style="width:100px;display:inline-block;">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`display:inline-block` makes sure more than one div can display on the same line

`white-space:nowrap` forces all the divs to be on one line

`overflow:auto` enables the scrollbar(s) if needed